# Not able to add the fragments using Kotlin Extension function

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I have a Kotlin extension function to add a fragment which is in another Kotlin file

```
fun Fragment.addFragment(tag: String?, id: Int, fragmentManager: FragmentManager) {
  // will take care of adding the fragment.
  val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
  fragmentTransaction.add(id, this, tag)
  fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(tag)
  fragmentTransaction.commit()
}
```

But whenever I am using that extension function to add a fragment then I am getting this crash

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.app.Fragment.setNextAnim(int)' on a null object reference
```

I am using that extension function like this:

```
MyFragment().addFragment("MyFragment", R.id.frame, fragmentMaganer)
```

After the above statement if I tried to debug my code then its executed successfully till

```
fragmentTransaction.commit()
```

but after that in the **onStart()** method of my activity I am facing that NullPointerException issue

But if I use the same code directly in Activity like this:

```
val myFragment = MyFragment()
val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frame, myFragment, tag)
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(tag)
fragmentTransaction.commit()
```

then Its working fine. Can someone please explain why its no working with **Extension function**?

Comment: Did you misspelling this `fun Fragment.addFragment()`?

Comment: No @nhoxbypass I did not

Comment: This not the right use of extension. What you did is you are creating a Fragment Instance just to use the method that creates another Fragment. I am guessing that you mistook it as static utilities?

Comment: @pk4393 yes it is

Comment: The extension function would make more sense if you created this extension function in `SupportFragmentManager` as `SupportFragmentManager.addFragment()`

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem, when I created a separate function to instantiate and finalize fragments.

But when my app was exiting, I wasn't creating a last transaction to remove the leftover fragment.

What I did was this: Before finalizing the application, remove the last fragment existing through a beginTransaction and commit. And the error has stopped happening.

I think my solution might give you some idea.